# Why hasn't my mulberry tree grown any leaves yet? It was bare root stock 8ft tall and is still alive after planting at end of April Zone 6

Tags: foliage

The trunk had swollen nodes that looked like leaves were going to come but never did.  I did a scrape and there is still green under layer.  What can I do to ensure success?

Comment: a photo and location is very helpful, how often have you been watering it?